# One route for different controller's actions

Tags: php, laravel

I want to use one route for one controller but different actions. I woud like to switch the action of controller by the current value in session, but don't change the route (current url in browser).

I tried this code:

```
$token = session('stravaAccessToken');
$athlete = session('stravaAthlete');
$stats = session('stravaStats');

if (empty($token) || empty($athlete) || empty($stats)) {
    Route::get('/', 'StravaController@login');
} else {
    Route::get('/', 'StravaController@index');
}
```

but, the session values returned always null (may be values are cached?!)

I woud like to use there code below, but there don't work as need... I have the session values as right as well, but, I don't understand, what do I need to return from callback function?

```
Route::get('/', function(){
    $token = session('stravaAccessToken');
    $athlete = session('stravaAthlete');
    $stats = session('stravaStats');

    if (empty($token) || empty($athlete) || empty($stats)) {
        Route::get('/', 'StravaController@login');
    } else {
        Route::get('/', 'StravaController@index');
    }
});
```

php 7.1, laravel 5.8

for first variant of code: always opened an action 'StravaController@login', 
for second variant of code: opened blank page

I woud like to expect an action 'StravaController@index' (is session values not empty) or an action 'StravaController@login' (if session values are empty)

Comment: Is it not just easier to do this in the controller contructor?

Comment: I know about controller constructor, but I would like to understand some features, what I can't found in docs. For example, how can I change 'controller@action' in route's callback... If it possible, of course

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Send everything to one function:

```
Route::get('/', 'StravaController@handle');
```

and have that function call the `login`/`index` functions accordingly:

```
public function handle() {
    $token = session('stravaAccessToken');
    $athlete = session('stravaAthlete');
    $stats = session('stravaStats');

    if (empty($token) || empty($athlete) || empty($stats)) {
        return $this->login();
    } else {
        return $this->index();
    }
}
```

An alternative option would be putting the login page on a different route, and having middleware redirect to it if the "logged in" data isn't present.

Comment: okay... but can I do it in web route config? or it is not impossible?

Comment: @АнтонХороший No, you cannot do this in the web route config. (In part because sessions aren't yet available at that point, and in part because you're supposed to cache the route config in production.)